# Making the Android ListView Row fit the image that it contains, and not bigger

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a Android list , and I want to make my “ListView” 's row dimensions to match the actual Image that’s inside it. Currently the row is larger than the image inside it, therefore distorting the list.

Please see below:

[image]

```
My activity (ActivitytToyotaOwnersMainListView.java, related code only):


public class ActivitytToyotaOwnersMainListView extends Activity {


    public ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_toyota_owners_main);

        ListViewItemModelLoader.LoadModel();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.toyota_owners_main_list_view);

        if (listView!=null)
        {

        String[] ids = new String[ListViewItemModelLoader.Items.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++){

            ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        }

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.main_activity_view_icons, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {   Log.d("***Class ActivitytToyotaOwnersMainListView, listView: ",
                String.valueOf(listView));

        }


        // OnItemClickListener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
......
```

ActivitytToyotaOwnersMainListView layout xml (activity_toyota_owners_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ToyotaOwnersMainActivity" >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/toyota_owners_main_list_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
   </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My ItemAdapter (Custom Adapter for displaying images in the list)

```
package com.toyota.toyotaownerspoc.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.toyota.toyotaownerspoc.R;

public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] Ids;
    private final int rowResourceId;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.Ids = objects;
        this.rowResourceId = textViewResourceId;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = null;
        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = null;
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (inflater != null) {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
                if (rowView != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                            .findViewById(R.id.main_activity_icons_image_view);

                    if (imageView != null) {
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
                        String resourceId = ListViewItemModelLoader.GetbyId(id).resourceFile;

                        // load image as Drawable
                        int resource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                                resourceId, "drawable",
                                context.getPackageName());
                        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                                resource);

                        // set image to ImageView
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

                    } else {
                        Log.d("***Class ItemAdapter , imageView: ",
                                String.valueOf(imageView));

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("***Class ItemAdapter , rowView: ",
                            String.valueOf(rowView));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("***Class ItemAdapter , inflater: ",
                        String.valueOf(inflater));
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.d("***Class ItemAdapter , getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent): ",
                    exc.getMessage());
        } finally {

            return rowView;
        }

    }

}
```

The layout of the image that is going to be inside every ListView row (main_activity_view_icons.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="64dp">
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_icons_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the minHeight parameter inside the RelatiiveLayout of your row layout. Try removing that.
Also, try to set the layout width / height of the relative layout and the image view there to "wrap content"

Hope this helps.

Comment: My new main_activity_view_icons.xml , with width & height set to "wrap-content" : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_icons_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   </ImageView>
   
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: I changed the layout , but still no change, there seems to be a implicit padding around the Image/ImageView, although neither my code or the layout specify padding. Also note my image is actually much larger , the framework is actually auto sizing the image.

Comment: ok, this might be a long shot, but it's worked for me a few times... try changing the relative layout to a linear layout. for some reason, relative layouts don't work very well with wrapping content.

Comment: @ Gil Moshayof , Thanks Gil , I changed the layout to Linear but still having the same issue. One thing that I noticed is that if I change the image sizes to 50% of the original everything “almost” fits, but there is still small gaps between the list, this reiterates my original hypothesis that there is a implicit padding/gap being added horizontally. How do I get rid of this gap??? Thanks

Comment: @  Gil Moshayof, Android, could the extra margin be due to the fact that the margin is calculated before the image is resized automatically by the framework, therefore the margin is based on the original image size??? If so how can I resize/update the margin around the item in the list , after it has loaded??? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="64dp">
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_icons_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the xml, but the issue still exists , refer to my comment above.

Comment: @ Hi-Tech KitKat Android, could the extra margin be due to the fact that the margin is calculated before the image is resized automatically by the framework, therefore the margin is based on the original image size??? If so how can I resize/update the margin around the item in the list , after it has loaded??? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use..

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

inside your ImageView for **remove** your extra spaces

**or**

you can **scale** your image to fit your screen because your image is **larger** then your screen width..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up having too explicitly specify the height of the ImageView. Basically the ImageView layout_height should specify the same value as your row height from the layout minHeight attribute. In your case that would look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="64dp">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_icons_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter">        
   </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

scaleType to fitCenter did not do it on its own for me.